# Troubleshooting Azure Service Fabric Deployment Issues

Tags: c#, .net, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I am using service fabric on my local dev cluster. It is giving error in publishing the application on visual studio output window as service not ready.

On looking at the fabric explorer. it is giving generic error **Source =System.FM. Partition is below target count.** I have checked the configurations and all are fine. How do I troubleshoot this?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you specify an instance count or replicaset size larger than 1 in the application parameters on a single node dev cluster? Is the service code crashing?

Comment: yes I did. Earlier the application was working fine. But in a collaborative environment I want to know how to troubleshoot in such a case as going through everyone's commits is not feasible.

Comment: Try changing these counts to 1, in the file `ApplicationParameters\Local.1Node.xml` or use the 5 node dev-cluster.

Comment: Done but same issue again.

Comment: One more issue I am facing is the errors are not clearly displayed by Service Fabric, it may be due to a configuration error or permission error. Is there any way to make debugging easier in Service Fabric?

Comment: you can try using monitoring tools like OMS and AppInsights https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-analysis-appinsights

Comment: Hey I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: You can debug the application, there are some unhandled exceptions in your code which is causing this to happen.